# Not sure where "if $p(1)=0$ then $p(x)=(x-1)(ax+b)$" comes from in a proof

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image: Here is the question]

[image: Here is the solution]

Really I'm only confused about a, I understand how the other answers were obtained but I'm shaky on what's going in part a. Any help is appreciated.

In particular I don't understand where if p(1)=0 then p(x)=(x-1)(ax+b) comes from.

Comment: What about the answer do you not get? Its hard to help out when you don't specify what you are having difficulty with. Context is important since maybe someone will post an answer that is not targeted at your concerns.

Comment: @PaulPlummer You're right I added some more context to try to explain what I don't understand.

Comment: Are you wondering where the $ax+b$ part comes from in particular or just the whole thing?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the $a, b$ in the answer are not necessarily the same as the $a,b$ from the description of $\mathcal P_2$.

Answer (score 1):

First note that a quadratic with a real root has no complex roots (you can look at the quadratic formula to see that). Also note that if a non-zero polynomial $p$ is zero at a point $a$, $p(a)=0$, then $p(x)=(x-a)q(x)$ where $q(x)$ is one degree lower than $p$, I am guessing this is the factor theorem that is being sited, or maybe the fundamental theorem of algebra.

In your problem $p$ is a quadratic or linear and $p(1)=0$, so $p(x)=(x-1)q(x)$, where $q$ is a degree one polynomial or a constant (depending on whether or not $p$ is quadratic or linear). We also have that $p$ has one real root so if it has another it is also real, so you can assume $q(x)=ax+b$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$.

(Edit: I just read the problem more carefully and it seems that paragraph one was all explained in the problem statement, so not sure if I cleared anything up for you.)

Comment: I just don't understand how we make the leap from there to (x-1)(ax+b).

Comment: @user113528 Did the second paragraph in my answer clear that up? I think you will need to try to explain more about what about the leap your not sure about  either in my answer or the answer given if mine did not clear anything up.

Comment: Ok I might be understanding it now. If P(2)=0 would you use p(x)=(x-2)(ax+b) ?

Edit: Nevermind , that doesn't make any sense. It's late, I'll sleep on this and try to understand more tomorrow. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user113528 Yes.

Comment: Oh wow, I get it then. Thank you!

Comment: @user113528 No problem